# CSS to force margin and padding to 0 of all divs except the ones inside <header> and <footer>

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i have been trying to write specific CSS which will force all divs in the document to have no margin and no padding.

Any ideas how i would achieve this?

I have tried:

```
body > div:not(header) {
     margin: 0 ;
     padding: 0 ;
}


div:not(header){
     margin:0 !important;
     padding:0 !important;
 }
```

These examples will either not work or still also change the divs inside header and/or footer

Some context, i am creating a custom wordpress template which comes with a plugin, in which i need all elements to have no margin and padding except for the global theme header and footer elements, since i do not want to change these.

Comment: Change the body > div:not(header) to body > *:not(header) and don'r use the div:not(header) because it will affect all divs.

Comment: So `<header>` and `<footer>` are part of div's?

Comment: `div:not(header)` makes zero sense to begin with. You are saying here, “select all the element with the tag name `div`, that do not have the tag name `header`” - which is of course _every_ div, no HTML element has _two_ tag names.

Comment: _“Some context”_ … would be nice, yes. And in this case, that means first of all a proper example of the HTML you want to apply this CSS to. Yes, we _could_ probably guess that in an instance like this - but we should not have to. And if we guessed wrong, and misunderstood what you meant, we’d be pointlessly discussing a different problem. Please go read [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I am sorry i just learned today about :not, and i thought the question would be small enough to not need an example

Comment: Using `:not()` “freely” in a selector chain seldom makes sense, resp. will not achieve the desired result - because if any arbitraty level of elements in between are allowed, there’s usually one that does _not_ match the `:not()` selector, and therefor makes the whole selector match again. It is more useful in situations, where you can “nail” it to a specific position - like for example `body > :not(header) div`. This would affect all `div` that are inside a container element that is itself a direct child of body, _and_ not of type `header`.

Comment: But then you can _not_ go with `body > :not(header) div, body > :not(footer) div` again - because _all_ divs will be either not in the header, **or** not in the footer (can’t be in both at the same time.) So you would have to apply the two “restrictions” at the same time - `body > :not(header):not(footer) div`

Comment: Is it me or it's just as simple as `div { padding:0;margin:0; } header div { padding:initial;margin:initial;}`

Comment: @CBroe your answer worked i did body > :not(footer):not(header) > div , if you like to put this as the answer i will mark it correct.

Comment: Sure, happy to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `:not()` “freely” in a selector chain seldom makes sense, resp. will not achieve the desired result - because if any arbitrary level of elements in between are allowed, there’s usually one that does not match the `:not()` selector, and therefor makes the whole selector match again.

It is more useful in situations, where you can “nail” it to a specific position - like for example

`body > :not(header) div`

This would affect all `div` that are inside a container element that is itself a direct child of body, and not of type `header`.

But then you can not go with `body > :not(header) div, body > :not(footer) div` again - because all divs will be either not in the `header`, *or* not in the `footer` (can’t be in both at the same time.)

So you would have to apply the two “restrictions” at the same time:

`body > :not(header):not(footer) div`

This affects all divs that descendants of a child of body, *if* that child itself is not `header` *and* not `footer`.